# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title) and more

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I want to when 'edit=true' a form with pre populated data should render ortherwise just redirect me. But i keep getting redirected and getting a console error 'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title')' this happens for my price,imagUrl etc in my pug files

Admin Js folder

```
const Product = require('../models/product');

exports.getAddProduct = (req, res, next) => {
    //res.render(path.join(rootDir, 'views', '/add-product.pug'))
      res.render('admin/edit-product', 
      {pageTitle: 'Add Product', 
      path: '/admin/add-product',
      editing: false
     });
   }

exports.postAddProduct=  (req, res, next) => {
    const title = req.body.title;
    const imageUrl = req.body.imageUrl;
    const price = req.body.price;
    const description = req.body.description;
    const product = new Product(title, imageUrl, description, price);
    product.save();
    res.redirect('/');
};

exports.getEditProduct = (req, res, next) => {
      const editMode = req.query.edit;
      if (!editMode) {
          return res.redirect('/');
      }
      const prodId = req.params.productId;
      Product.findById(prodId, product => {
          if (!product) {
              res.redirect('/')
          }
        res.render('admin/edit-product', 
        {pageTitle: 'Edit Product', 
        path: '/admin/edit-product',
        editing: editMode, 
        product: product
       });
      });
   };

exports.getProducts = (req, res, next) => {
    Product.fetchAll((products) => {
        res.render('admin/products', {
        prods: products, 
        pageTitle: 'Admin Products',
        path: '/admin/products'
        });
    });
}
```

products.js file

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const products = [];

const p = path.join(
    path.dirname(process.mainModule.filename), 
    'data', 
    'products.json'
    );

const getProductsFromFile = cb => {
    fs.readFile(p, (err, fileContent) => {
        if (err) {
        cb([]);
        } else {
        cb(JSON.parse(fileContent));
        }
    });
};

module.exports = class Products {
    constructor(title, imageUrl, description, price) {
        this.title = title;
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
        this.description = description;
        this.price = price;
    }

    save() {
       this.id = Math.random().toString();
       getProductsFromFile(products => {
        products.push(this);
        fs.writeFile(p, JSON.stringify(products), (err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
       });
    };

    static fetchAll(cb) {
        getProductsFromFile(cb)
    }

    static findById(id, cb) {
        getProductsFromFile(products => {
            const product = products.find(p => p.id === id);
            cb(product);
        })
    }
};
```

edit-product.pug

```
extends ../layouts/main-layout.pug 

block styles    
    link(rel="stylesheet", href="/css/product.css")
    link(rel="stylesheet", href="/css/forms.css")

block content
    main  
        .main-form
            if editing
                form(action="/admin/edit-product", method="POST")
                    .main-input
                        label(for="title") Title  
                        input(type="text", name="title", placeholder="Search Product", value=product.title) 
                    .main-input
                        label(for="imageUrl") Image URL 
                        input(type="url", name="imageUrl", id="imageUrl", value=product.imageUrl)
                    .main-input
                        label(for="price") Price
                        input(type="number", name="price", id="price", step="0.01", value=product.price) 
                    .main-input
                        label(for="description", value=product.description) Description
                        textarea(name="description", id="description", rows="5") 
                    .main-button  
                        if editing  
                            button.btn(type="submit") Update Product 
                        else 
                            button.btn(type="submit") Add Product
            else
                form(action="/admin/add-product", method="POST")
                    .main-input
                        label(for="title") Title  
                        input(type="text", name="title", placeholder="Search Product") 
                    .main-input
                        label(for="imageUrl") Image URL 
                        input(type="url", name="imageUrl", id="imageUrl")
                    .main-input
                        label(for="price") Price
                        input(type="number", name="price", id="price", step="0.01") 
                    .main-input
                        label(for="description") Description
                        textarea(name="description", id="description", rows="5") 
                    .main-button  
                        if editing  
                            button.btn(type="submit") Update Product 
                        else 
                            button.btn(type="submit") Add Product
```

product.pug file

```
extends ../layouts/main-layout.pug 

block styles    
    link(rel="stylesheet", href="/css/main.css")
    link(rel="stylesheet", href="/css/card.css")

block content
    main 
        if prods.length > 0
            .grid 
                each product in prods
                    article.product-item 
                        header.card__header 
                            h1.product__title #{product.title}
                        .card__image 
                            img(src=`${product.imageUrl}` 
                            alt="#{product.title}")
                        .card__content 
                            h2.product__price #{product.price}
                            p.product__description #{product.description}
                        .card__actions 
                            a(href="/admin/edit-product/:product.id:?edit=true") Edit 
                            form(action="/admin/delete-product" method="POST")
                                .btn
                                    button(class="btn", type="submit")  Remove
        else 
            h1 No Product
```

PAY CLOSE ATTENTION TO MY 'a' tag in products.pug file.  Thats where the problem is coming from i think. Format may be off trying to follow a handlebars tutorial and they can set query params within the file but in pug i guess its different

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I pass a parameter back from an anchor tag.

```
a( href='editticket/'+ticket.id ) ticket.id
```

this will go to a route that looks like this:

```
app.get('/editticket/:ticketId', (req,res, next)=>{
  tktRoute.showTicket(req, res).catch(next);
});
```

The showTicket route retrieves the item and displays it on the form.